# MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.ALBUM_ART returns -1

Tags: android, mediastore, audio-player, android-music-player

I am trying to play songs in my app. But I am not able to get Album art from album columns. I don't want to use `MediaMetadataRetriever` as it eats a lot of memory when I am populating my list. Here is the code:

```
 ContentResolver musicResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
        Uri musicUri = (MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI );

    Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);

    if(musicCursor!=null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()){

        int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
        int albumArtColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.ALBUM_ART);

            }
```

I have searched for it everywhere but couldn't find a good answer.

### Cursor dump below

```
0 {
_id=11874
_data=/storage/emulated/0/Music/Bang Bang (2014)/01 - Tu Meri - DownloadMing.SE.mp3
_display_name=01 - Tu Meri - DownloadMing.SE.mp3
_size=8349428
mime_type=audio/mpeg
date_added=1437797205
is_drm=0
date_modified=1435229092
title=Tu Meri - DownloadMing.SE
title_key=  O   Q       A   1   K   9       
    /   E   U   C   ?   E   )   /   A   9   C   5   M   1
duration=257149
artist_id=5
composer=Music: Shekhar Ravjiani & Vishal Dadlani | DownloadMing.SE
album_id=5
track=0
year=2014
is_ringtone=0
is_music=1
is_alarm=null
is_notification=0
is_podcast=null
bookmark=null
album_artist=DownloadMing.SE
artist_id:1=5
artist_key= S   9   M   7   )   ?       /   )   /   ?   )   C   9
artist=Vishal Dadlani
album_id:1=5
album_key=  +   )   C   5       +   )   C   5                       462492867
album=Bang Bang (2014)
}
1 {
_id=11875
_data=/storage/emulated/0/Music/Bang Bang (2014)/02 - Meherbaan - DownloadMing.SE.mp3
_display_name=02 - Meherbaan - DownloadMing.SE.mp3
_size=10255537
mime_type=audio/mpeg
date_added=1437797205
is_drm=0
date_modified=1435229093
title=Meherbaan - DownloadMing.SE
title_key=  A   1   7   1   K   +   )   )   C       
    /   E   U   C   ?   E   )   /   A   9   C   5   M   1
duration=307461
artist_id=6
composer=Music: Shekhar Ravjiani & Vishal Dadlani | DownloadMing.SE
album_id=5
track=0
year=2014
is_ringtone=0
is_music=1
is_alarm=null
is_notification=0
is_podcast=null
bookmark=null
album_artist=DownloadMing.SE
artist_id:1=6
artist_key= )   M   7       =   9   C   5       M   7   9   ?   G   )       K   )   E               M   7   1   =   7   )   K       K   )   S   ;   9   )   C   9
artist=Ash King, Shilpa Rao & Shekhar Ravjiani
album_id:1=5
album_key=  +   )   C   5       +   )   C   5                       462492867
album=Bang Bang (2014)
}
2 {
_id=11876
_data=/storage/emulated/0/Music/Bang Bang (2014)/03 - Uff - DownloadMing.SE.mp3
_display_name=03 - Uff - DownloadMing.SE.mp3
_size=9049421
mime_type=audio/mpeg
date_added=1437797205
is_drm=0
date_modified=1435229093
title=Uff - DownloadMing.SE
title_key=  Q   3   3       
    /   E   U   C   ?   E   )   /   A   9   C   5   M   1
duration=272170
artist_id=7
composer=Music: Shekhar Ravjiani & Vishal Dadlani | DownloadMing.SE
album_id=5
track=0
year=2014
is_ringtone=0
is_music=1
is_alarm=null
is_notification=0
is_podcast=null
bookmark=null
album_artist=DownloadMing.SE
artist_id:1=7
artist_key= 7   )   K   M   7   /   1   1   G       =   )   Q   K               +   1   C   C   Y       /   )   Y   )   ?
artist=Harshdeep Kaur & Benny Dayal
album_id:1=5
album_key=  +   )   C   5       +   )   C   5                       462492867
album=Bang Bang (2014)
}
3 {
_id=11877
_data=/storage/emulated/0/Music/Bang Bang (2014)/04 - Bang Bang - DownloadMing.SE.mp3
_display_name=04 - Bang Bang - DownloadMing.SE.mp3
_size=10613831
mime_type=audio/mpeg
date_added=1437797205
is_drm=0
date_modified=1435229094
title=Bang Bang - DownloadMing.SE
title_key=  +   )   C   5       +   )   C   5       
    /   E   U   C   ?   E   )   /   A   9   C   5   M   1
duration=320078
artist_id=8
composer=Music: Shekhar Ravjiani & Vishal Dadlani | DownloadMing.SE
album_id=5
track=0
year=2014
is_ringtone=0
is_music=1
is_alarm=null
is_notification=0
is_podcast=null
bookmark=null
album_artist=DownloadMing.SE
artist_id:1=8
artist_key= +   1   C   C   Y       /   )   Y   )   ?               C   1   1   O   9       A   E   7   )   C
artist=Benny Dayal & Neeti Mohan
album_id:1=5
album_key=  +   )   C   5       +   )   C   5                       462492867
album=Bang Bang (2014)
}
4 {
_id=11878
_data=/storage/emulated/0/Music/Bang Bang (2014)/05 - Meherbaan (Reprise) - DownloadMing.SE.mp3
_display_name=05 - Meherbaan (Reprise) - DownloadMing.SE.mp3
_size=5858173
mime_type=audio/mpeg
date_added=1437797205
is_drm=0
date_modified=1435229095
title=Meherbaan (Reprise) - DownloadMing.SE
title_key=  A   1   7   1   K   +   )   )   C       K   1   G   K   9   M   1       
    /   E   U   C   ?   E   )   /   A   9   C   5   M   1
duration=181551
artist_id=9
composer=Music: Shekhar Ravjiani & Vishal Dadlani | DownloadMing.SE
album_id=5
```

Comment: just use `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor` so see it on the logcat

Comment: @pskink I have checked the value returned by  {musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.ALBUM_ART);} and that is -1. If I try to access that column it gives error.

Comment: just use `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor` so see it on the logcat

Comment: you can use `ALBUM_ART` only in Uris that support `MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns` that is: `MediaStore.Audio.Albums` and `MediaStore.Audio.Artists.Albums`

Comment: @pskink The cursor should have some album art atleast. As I am able to fetch the artwork by MediaMetadataRetriever .

Comment: did you try **DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor** ???

Comment: so it has columns from: `MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns`, right? and those are you can use for your `Cursor`, this is because `MediaStore.Audio.Media` implements `MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns`

Comment: so you can use: `MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ALBUM_ID`, `MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ALBUM` and `MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ALBUM_KEY`

Comment: @pskink Sorry but how can I get album art from the columns you have mentioned. To fetch album art I was using this: `MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.ALBUM_ART `  which is giving -1 index.

Comment: see classes implementing `MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns` you have the id to those tables stored in `MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ALBUM_ID`: in your case `album_id` = 5 and album title is "Bang Bang (2014)"

Comment: @pskink it is album art which I am asking about.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85279/discussion-between-theoddabhi-and-pskink).

Answer (score 0):

The reason I was getting `MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.ALBUM_ART returns -1` was because I had made the cursor for URI `MediaStore.Audio.Media` not for `MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns`.

Thanks to @pskink for the help.